# Floating DIVs like on pintrest.com

Tags: html, css

I've got a little problem. I have multiple relative positioned DIVs in an absolute positioned wrapper div. Now I want them to be like on pintrest.com. But my result looks like this:

http://d.pr/CHCq
(Image link on droplr.com)

CSS:

```
div.post {
position: relative;
width: 250px;
margin: 0 0px 14px 14px;
background-color: #eae9e9;
float: left;
}
```

Do you know any efficient fix for this? Or shall I make three columns?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might consider using [jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).  Or, if you're alright with the width being static, 3 columns as you mentioned.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thank you very much! That plugin solved it perfectly! Please add an answer and I'll set it as "accepted answer".

Comment: Answer posted.  Happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using [jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Or, if you're alright with the width being static, 3 columns as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split them up into columns using either DIVs or TABLEs, and then make sure you have "vertical-align: top" set on the column containers.

Float won't do what you're wanting, nor will display: inline-block.

One alternative is to set the height of all boxes to be equal, and then use "display: inline-block" instead of float.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do the 3 columns as it will be the fastes solution for your issue and it will be effective as well.